# Is there a way to get temporary role based credentials using the AWS C++ SDK?

Tags: aws-sdk-cpp

ProfileConfigFileAWSCredentialsProvider used in DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain simply ignores roles in `~/.aws/config` and `~/.aws/credentials`. STSProfileCredentialsProvider appears as though it is meant to be used for this, but 1) it's not used in DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain so you have to explicitly use it, and 2) it only reads `config`. #2 means that if, for example, your role based profile specifies a source profile, and the source profile's credentials are in `credentials` then STSProfileCredentialsProvider will fail to find the source profile's credentials and then won't be able to get the role's temporary credentials.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually caused by an issue in the AWS C++ SDK where configurations with assumed roles are ignored by the DefaultCredentialsProviderChain: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/issues/150
However, we need to find a workaround as this was promised to be fixed "incredibly soon" back in 2016 and still isn't fixed, in fact the issue is now closed.

EDIT: There is another issue here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/issues/1330

It appears your only option is to find the active profile yourself using something like Aws::Config::GetCachedConfigProfile(Aws::Auth::GetConfigProfileName()) and then use GetRoleArn()/GetSourceProfile() and call the STS service yourself with the credentials from the source profile.

Please let me know if you find a better solution!